# Should [computer-chess] be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [computer-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-chess) has at the moment 4 followers and 29 questions.

It seems to me as it could be easily replaced using [engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) (12 followers, 280 questions). Furthermore, [engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) has [chess-computers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-computers) as a synonym, which seems to me quite similar to [computer-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-chess).

Should [computer-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-chess) be deleted / marked as synonym?

Answer (score 5):

To my mind, `computer-chess` refers to the chess games played by computers (or rather `engines` or `chess-computers` as you noted), so they are referring to slightly different things. So probably the questions should be re-tagged because one of the tags has been misused.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed [computer-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-chess) is frequently misused on questions about programming engines. I do not see why we need the slight distinction between games between engines and discussion about engines, as how an engine plays is an integral part of discussion about engines. I believe the tag should just be a synonym for [engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) as noted in the question.